# Read different chunks in text file in c#

Tags: c#, parsing, text

I'm building a forms app in visual c#. My problem is that I need to read all the columns underlined in Red (shown in picture ) and skip the columns which are in blue:

[image: Picture]

I dont know if I should use readline or readblock method. Also, how would the program know when a red column ends and how to go to the next red column. Will I have to use character counts?

This is my current code:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName));
            // constructor sr accesses streamreader class. In stream reader class we access method read to end
            textBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            // fill textbox with this.
            sr.Dispose();

        }
    }
```

I'm sorry for the vaugeness, I'm a beginner - really appreciate the help.

Comment: You'll probably want to read full lines and count characters to determine column...  The only useful way to skip file read sections would be `.Seek()` but I don't think that'll help here.  Stick to basics.  (Blocks are too small for `.Seek()` to be helpful)

Comment: @user2788405 In the current state,it's very difficult to achieve what you want because the file looks specially typical.Seems like this'll require very heavy parsing with lots of code as there is no common pattern or similar thing to consider.

Comment: @ebyrob Can you pls give me an example with code of how to use the character count for the first column? doesn't have to be anything major - just so I can see.
 I'm guessing I should read full lines and count characters like ebyrob said BUT what methods would I use for those?
I'm guessing readLine for lines, but what about characters?

Thanks guys

Comment: Where is this data coming from in terms of what sort of program is generating it? Is there any chance you could save this as some sort of serializable format rather than just a text file?

Comment: `string s = sr.ReadLine();` `s = s.PadRight(nMaxExpectedWidth);` `string col1 = s.Substring(15, 20).Trim();` This is very ugly, but works (more or less).  Reading line prefixes will tell you when you change "row sections" so you can process the lines differently.

Comment: guys thanks for the help. Data is coming from a folder with 1000s of textfiles. Im guessing you want me to put it in a database ?

@AviralSingh I dont have enough rep to upload files, can I email it to you

Comment: @user2788405 You can upload it [here](http://www.datafilehost.com).

Comment: @AviralSingh here's the download link http://www.datafilehost.com/d/1a00af75 - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like two very simple rules could help with these files:

1) Rows with a character in the first column (not space) kick you out of table mode.

2) Rows with groups of equal and space and nothing else in them start table mode.
   
a) column width defined by width of equal sign section
   
b) previous row usually gives column names

Using that you could create a general parser for this form of file.  Just read a line at a time and apply the rules for entering leaving table against each line you read.  (Keep one-back if you want header names)

**EDIT:** Added a code sample.  (problem is by the "first line" the whole program is mostly written)

```
using( StreamReader input = new StreamReader("somefile.txt") )
{
   List<int> bounds = new List<int>();
   for( string line = input.ReadLine(); line != null; line = input.ReadLine() )
   {
      if( line.Length > 0 && line[0] == '-' )
         bounds.Clear();
      if( Regex.IsMatch(line, "^ *=[ =]*$") ) // This is a column header
      {
         bounds.Clear();
         for( int i = 1; i<line.Length; ++i )
            if( line[i - 1] != line[i] )
               bounds.Add(i);
      }
      else if( bounds.Count > 0 )
      {
         List<string> cells = new List<string>();
         string padLine = line.PadRight(bounds[bounds.Count-1]);
         for( int i=0; i<bounds.Count; i += 2 )
            cells.Insert(i / 2, padLine.Substring(bounds[i], bounds[i+1]));
         // retrieve data cells[7] (column 7) here and store elsewhere.  
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey this makes sense. I like the simplicity of the parser. Quick question though, How do I start the text read at seq# column?

Comment: @user2788405 Same as before.  I suggest read one whole line (so you don't get lost) then do `line.Substring(start,end).Trim()`.  (start/end you'd hold in a list of column header info structs or something)

Comment: appreciate the help but can you code an example of going through the first line? Sorry i'm a newbie